# How to install pip for python3.4 when my pi have python3.2 and python3.4

Tags: python, installation, pip

How to install pip for python3.4 when my pi have python3.2 and python3.4

when I used `sudo install python3-pip`

it's only for python3.2

but I want install pip for python3.4

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.4 has `pip` included, see [*What's New in Python 3.4*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-pep-453).

Just execute:

```
python3.4 -m ensurepip
```

to install it if it is missing for you. See the [`ensurepip` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) for further details.

Comment: I had try it,but   `Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 6.0.8 requires SSL/TLS` , have other way?? -.-!

Comment: @weijia.wang: without SSL support you won't be able to *use* `pip` anyway. How did you set up your Python 3.4 installation? Did you compile it from source? If so, you need to install the openssl header files too.

Comment: @weijia.wang: on a Ubuntu or Debian based Raspberry you can install the `libssl-dev` package to get those headers, then recompile. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447635/installing-distribute-in-python-3-3-ubuntu/16447683#16447683) for a more complete list of packages you may want to install before compiling Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your python 3.4 directory scripts and run it's pip in:

`../python3.4/scripts`

Comment: my python3.4 in `/opt/python3.4.3/`   but in  `python3.4.3/bin` I can't find any file about pip

Answer (score 0):

You should compile python 3.4 and use venv for python3 environment:

1. Check if you have installed required dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential

   sudo apt-get install libc6-dev libreadline-dev libz-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev tk-dev
   ```
2. Download and compile Python 3.4.3. You should not `sudo make install` it because we don't need it systemwide:

   ```
   wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/Python-3.4.3.tgz
   tar -xvf Python-3.4.3.tgz
   cd Python-3.4.3 
   ./configure && make
   ```

   This may take a while on pi.
3. While you still in current folder, create python environment:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.virtualenvs
   ./python -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/py34
   ```
4. launch your virtual environment:

   ```
   source ~/.virtualenvs/py34/bin/activate
   ```

Now you have Python 3.4 and pip inside of it. Try:

```
    pip install bpython
```

To exit virtual environment use:

```
    deactivate
```